# Query using case and update the last record

Tags: mysql

I have two tables
oc_stock_hpp

```
id product_id stock
2  1234       0
3  5678       6
4  1234       2
6  1234       3
9  5678       7
```

oc_product

```
id product_id quantity
1  1234       7
23 5678       9
```

My purpose is to update the difference value (between SUM(stock) and quantity) in the stock field table oc_stock_hpp.

- If the SUM(stock) > quantity then subtract the difference from the last record of stock
- If the SUM(stock) > quantity then add the difference from the last record of stock

so the result will be like this

```
id product_id stock
2  1234       0
3  5678       6
4  1234       2
6  1234       5
9  5678       3
```

I have tried this but error

```
CASE 
WHEN SUM(shpp1.stock) > p.quantity 
    THEN UPDATE oc_stock_hpp shpp1 INNER JOIN oc_product p ON shpp1.product_id = p.product_id 
        SET shpp1.stock = (shpp1.stock - ((SELECT SUM(shpp2.stock) FROM oc_stock_hpp shpp2 LEFT JOIN oc.product p WHERE shpp2.product_id = p.product_id) - p.quantity)
            WHERE shpp1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM (SELECT * FROM oc_stock_hpp) o1 WHERE product_id = p.product_id)
WHEN SUM(shpp1.stock) < p.quantity  
    THEN UPDATE oc_stock_hpp shpp1 INNER JOIN oc_product p ON shpp1.product_id = p.product_id 
        SET shpp1.stock = (shpp1.stock + (p.quantity - (SELECT SUM(shpp2.stock) FROM oc_stock_hpp shpp2 LEFT JOIN oc.product p WHERE shpp2.product_id = p.product_id))
            WHERE shpp1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM (SELECT * FROM oc_stock_hpp) o1 WHERE product_id = p.product_id)
END
FROM oc_product p
LEFT JOIN oc_stock_hpp shpp ON shpp.product_id = p.product_id
```

Comment: `SUM()` needs to be in a query with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I guess that the one of  *ifs* of your conditions should be: "If the SUM(stock) < quantity..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the 2 tables to a query that returns the last id and total stock for each product:

```
UPDATE oc_stock_hpp s
INNER JOIN oc_product p ON p.product_id = s.product_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id, SUM(stock) stock FROM oc_stock_hpp GROUP BY product_id) t ON t.id = s.id
SET s.stock = s.stock + p.quantity - t.stock;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=377c26f0208c576615e735df68126c5c).